# Coloring Individual Pixels

Tags: java, colors, rgb, pixel

i'm trying to write a program with Java what generates images by coloring individual pixels with RGB by adding up the value of every RGB-channel by one until it reaches 255 and then adds one on the next RGB channel.

Here an example:

RED is set to 0
GREEN is set to 0
BLUE is set to 0

1. RED gets added up by one (RED ++)on the first pixel until it reaches 255.
2. After RED reaches 255 RED gets set to 0 and GREEN gets added up by one (GREEN ++).
3. The RED channel gets added up again like in step 1 until 255 and then step 2 follows again.
4. If GREEN is 255 the same method is used for BLUE means that one gets added to BLUE while GREEN and RED will be set to 0 again. Then step 1 again.
5. After all channels in the first Pixel are 255 the second pixel gets one up on its RED channel. Then it should begin by step 1 again until the second Pixel has a value of 255 on RED, what will set RED back to 0 and GREEN gets one up on the second pixel and so on and so on....

I'm sorry for my bad english and for my limited Java-knowledge.

This is my whole code so far(Stuff in comments is either not important in the project no more, not ready to use or i don't understand how to use it xD):

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
//import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
//import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Quadrat 
{   
  public static void main (String[] args)
  { int x = 100;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int Max = 255;
    int height = 500;
    int width = 500;

    if (x < Max){
    x ++;
    } else {
        x = 0;
        y ++;
    }
    if (y > Max){
        y = 0;
        z ++;
        } 

    if (z > Max){
        z = 0;
        } 


    JFrame Bild = new JFrame("Bildergenerator");
    Bild.setSize(width,height);
    Bild.setVisible(true);


    Color Kartoffel = new Color(x, y, z, 255);
    BufferedImage Test = new BufferedImage(300, 200, 
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics graphics = Test.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Kartoffel);
    graphics.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    graphics.dispose();
    Test.setRGB(1, 1, Kartoffel.getRGB());

  }


    /*System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(z);*/
    //img.setRGB(x,y,z);




/*    JFrame Test = new JFrame("Jframe1");
      JLabel Label = new JLabel("");
      Test.add(Label);
      Test.setSize(xx,yy);
      Test.setVisible(true);
      Test.setLocation(x/2-(xx/2), y/2-(yy/2));*/



  /* JFrame Hyaeaeae = new JFrame("BurrScurrSWAG");
      Hyaeaeae.setSize(1000,1000);
      Hyaeaeae.setVisible(true);
      Hyaeaeae.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.RED);*/




    }
```

I'll hope you can help me in any way and if so i'm very thankful! 
Thank you for your Attention!
Have a nice day! c:

Comment: Hi. What do you expect to have exactly? if you fill the first pixel with the three colors at 255!! and go on! do you have an image to show to us?

Comment: OK, so you've described what your program is supposed to do, and you posted some code. But it looks like you forgot to ask a specific question - what exactly is your question? Does the program do what you expect, or does it do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the timer for this as your code is just changing on the first iteration on startup after this nothing is changed so a timer to make sure increments keep on applied on variables

```
package javatestapp;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaTestApp extends TimerTask
{
    static int x = 100;
    static int y = 0;
    static int z = 0;
    static int Max = 255;
    static int height = 500;
    static int width = 500; 
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InitFrame();
    }

    public static void incrementValues()
    {
        if (x < Max)
        {
           x ++;
        }
        else
        {
           x = 0;
           y ++;
        }

        if (y > Max)
        {
           y = 0;
           z ++;
        } 

        if (z > Max)
        {
          x = 0;
          y = 0;
          z = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void genImage()
    {
        Color color = new Color(x,y,z,255);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(color);
    }

    public static void InitFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Bildergenerator");
        frame.setSize(width,height);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        TimerTask timerTask = new JavaTestApp();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10);
    } 

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        incrementValues();
        genImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, but i think something went wrong ....

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at JavaTestApp.main(JavaTestApp.java:18)

Comment: I figured out the issue! It's "package javatestapp;"

Comment: rename the package you are using and let me know further

Comment: i just took it out of the code and it worked perfectly fine. Sorry for the long time without an answer :D

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for my vote to be shown but it counts still!